Why does my Mac mini 2010 turn off as soon as I see my desktop?
When I install 2 x 1GB RAM modules and power on the Mac, it chimes, boots up ok, right up to showing the desktop and then it instantly shuts off. If I turn it back on, it does the same thing.
Originally it came with 2 x 1GB DDR3 1066 (PC3-8500) memory modules, but the previous owner upgraded it to 2 x 4GB modules (and an SSD). It runs fine in this configuration. However, I would like to restore this to original spec to keep it as a collectors item (don't ask why...), so I want to change the RAM. I have already replaced the SSD with an original HDD) and with the 2 x 4GB RAM modules it runs fine from the HDD.
I've sourced 2 x 1GB Hynix PC3-8500(S) modules, which as far as I can tell were commonly the factory installed brand (also Samsung).
If I reinstall the 2 x 4GB RAM modules, it boots fine and I can use the Mac with no issues. I should note that one is a Samsung 4GB PC3-10600S module and the other is a Crucial 4GB DDR3 1066MHz (so PC3-8500) module, so the working pair of modules aren't even a matched pair.
My head is telling me that a sudden shut off is a power supply issue. However, from experience, power supply issues are usually when more power is required, and I can't help but thinking that 2 x 4GB RAM modules would pull a bit more power than 2 x 1GB modules. Also, it's specifically at the point where the desktop image is displayed where it shuts off. I literally see the desktop image for a split second -- no dock or menu bar -- then it shuts off. The more power hungry part of the startup process is surely behind it, when it spins up the HDD and fan.
It's in great condition and I've fully disassembled it to clean it so cooling and everything is optimal. I don't hear any indications that heat is an issue (no fan noise above normal). But I just wanted to ensure this was clean and clear of dust, and also it was in as close to factory state as possible.
I have attempted to run AHT from the original disks, but this Mac appears to ignore that as it just seems to always look to pull this over the internet. I assume a firmware update has told it to do this, so nothing I try seems to get it to try to source the AHT from local media. When I do allow it to try to load AHT from the internet, AHT tells me that it is not supported on this machine.
I have used Rember to check each RAM module independently and they each check out. As soon as I put them together, the Mac won't fully boot to the desktop.
I have tried combining each module with one of the 4GB modules and the system boots and works fine. So it seems the modules are ok in themselves. But this Mac just doesn't like the two of them to be seen together...
Note that this is on a fresh install of 10.6 Snow Leopard on a HDD from the original installation media. I have applied all the 10.6 updates too.
Does anyone have any ideas why I can't run this Mac with the two 'original' RAM modules?

Is there any relevant logs in the console.app?

@hym3242 Sadly not. It seems to be normal bootup logging, then nothing, then the bootup messages from the next boot.

How about trying different boot modes? Maybe single-user mode? Recovery mode? Maybe verbose boot will allow you to see the logs before it powers down?

I get the same behaviour in single-user mode and recovery mode and also if I boot the installation media -- as soon as the language selection screen is shown, it turns off. I recorded the verbose output and it prints "Previous Shutdown Cause: -2" then "DSMOS has arrived" then the default blue background is displayed and then the Mac turns off.

-2 is not found on https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/, but is reported by others. @grg DSMOS seems to mean "don't steal macos" and is a common error in hackintosh.

If the original RAM causes the system to shut down and the "new" RAM does not, occam's razor says the simplest explanation is the answer. EG the 1GB original RAM is defective. It is not all that common these days but it does happen.

The 2010 Mini could be ordered from Apple with 2, 4 or 8Gb of RAM, so there's nothing "inauthentic" about that.

@SteveChambers I've tested each module on their own in this Mac and they are both fine

@benwiggy No, but it couldn't be ordered from Apple with a mixture of different brands and speeds of RAM
